# IOS app , searchbox and SQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, sql-server

I have a SQL webhosting database with a table described as "Description". Now the database speaks with my app completely fine but I seem to have a issue regarding multiple keywords in a search. As of right now the search will only find the first word typed in the searchbox inside the table 'Description' in my databse. So say if my user types in "Dragon Tattoo" via the searchbox in the app, It will display everything with "Dragon" only.. In conclusion, what is the best method to have my search box list any keywords with multiple words with spaces for an exact match.

Here is my server side PHP for the search function:

```
function _search($text){
    $dbObj=$this->CONN;
    $query="SELECT * FROM tatoo_user_info where description LIKE '%$text%' OR name  LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY create_date DESC";
    $stmt=$dbObj->prepare($query);      
    $res=$stmt->execute();
    $rows=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $resultant=array();
    foreach($rows as $values){
        $array=array();
        $array=$values;
        $query1="SELECT * FROM images where tui_id=:id";
        $stmt1=$dbObj->prepare($query1);        
        $stmt1->bindParam(':id',$values['id']);
        $res=$stmt1->execute();
        $row=$stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $arr_image=array();
        foreach($row as $images){
            $arr_image[]=$images['name'];
        }
    $resultant[]=array_merge($array,array("images"=>$arr_image));
    }
    //print_r($resultant);die;
    if(count($resultant)>=1){
        $result_a=array("status"=>"SUCCESS","message"=>"Successfully Fetched","data"=>$resultant);
        echo json_encode($result_a);

    }
    else{
        $result_a=array("status"=>"FAILURE","message"=>"Fail to find");
        echo json_encode($result_a);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about performance for this one but you can try with multiple queries:

```
$str = "Dragon Tattoo and much more";
$arr_words = explode(" ", $str);
foreach($arr_words as $word)
{
    $word = trim($word);
     $sql="SELECT * FROM tatoo_user_info where description LIKE '%$word%' OR name  LIKE '%$word%' ORDER BY create_date DESC";

}
```

or you can build one long query:

```
foreach($arr_words as $word){
    $sql .= " OR name LIKE '%$word%' and description LIKE '%$word%'... ";
}
```

Comment: Now would $Str be equal to $text or my search function. Because my main issue is getting more than one word for a search. I'm not necessarily using "dragon tattoo", that was just an example